# Faster navigation or switch between browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, emacs, browser-tabs

Is that such a plugin for chrome or other webbroswer that supports tab navigation by typing tab names?

My browser constantly has a lot of open tabs. It makes tab switching really difficult. I have to either navigate the tabs left/right using the shortcuts or click through the small tab icons to find a particular tab, both of which are very inefficient. Thus, I'm wondering if there is such a plugin that helps navigate the tabs by typing page keywords or page name. (If you're an Emacs user, this should ideally work like C-x b.) For example, when you type "super user" in the browser, jumps to the corresponding tab. Another nice-to-have feature is to prevent user from opening duplicate tabs, and group tabs by domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps for Chrome, [QuickTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) from the Chrome web store. Type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> and then type the title prefix and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. If this one isn't right, I suggest you search [the Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore).

Comment: Sweet!!! This is very close to what I had in mind Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, Tabhunter has got this feature.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabhunter/

The search for title/url or page text works for tabs in any window. Also, the keyboard shortcut is customizable.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your requirements

1. switching tabs by typing tab names
2. helps navigate the tabs by typing page keywords or page name
3. prevent user from opening duplicate tabs,
4. group tabs by domain name

I do not know if an extension provides these. But to help organize tabs (Req 4) [Microsoft introduced tab groups](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/09/23/our-top-new-features-are-designed-to-put-your-family-first/)

> we’re introducing tab groups in Microsoft Edge. Tab groups allow you
> to organize the chaos by clustering tabs together. You can add a name
> and a color to help you easily find them or collapse them to make more
> space for other tabs. To start a tab group, hold down CTRL and use
> your cursor to select the tabs you want to aggregate. Then right-click
> and select Add tabs to new group

[msedge](/questions/tagged/msedge) has a feature for vertical or horizontal tabs. These can be put in groups.

#### Horizontal tab group

Below you can see three `tab-groups`

- `ux echange` is the first group and has one tab
- `Edge_Developer` is the 2nd tab group and is collapsed. It contains two tabs (not visible)
- `Superuser` is the 3r tab group and collapsed as well.

[image: edge horizontal tab-groups]

#### Vertical tab group

[image: msedge vertical tabs in groups]

Comment: See [a proposol for horizontal tabs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/144853/)

Comment: See also Feature [suggestions for tab groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2be2b04d-e5ef-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008) and [better tab groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/65023321-6d9c-ec11-a81c-00224850e48f)